# Is it possible to put all the xml-comments of a solution into one xml-file?

Tags: c#, winforms, xml-comments

I have a Visual Studio C# solution with 3 different projects in it. In each of the projects I've commented all the code using xml-comments. If I want the comments build into xml, I have to specify a output file for each project. Is it possible to build all xml comments into one file?

Comment: You could use a post-build event and use an XSLT transformation to join the various XML files.

Comment: @driis - can you point me to an example of this?

Comment: actually, I don't have an example, I was just thinking out loud the steps I might take if I wanted to do it. Another idea would be to download Sandcastle and see it there might be parts in there that will help you (Sandcastle, is (among other things) a whole bunch of XSLT transformations, that work on the XML documentation files VS generates).

Comment: @driis - ok thanks. I'm going to look both into the post-build event and Sandcastle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a post build event with the copy command using the following syntax:

```
 copy file1.xml + file2.xml + fileN.xml destinationFile.xml
```

I would put this in the post build event for the main project that depends on everything else in the solution.

Comment: is there any code-based embedding? like project configuration or in-code concatenation